# common method and method body with one changing method parameter

Tags: java

We have a common method as below:

```
public class CommomClass()
{
    public String[] commonMethod(Object1 inputObject1)
    {
        String[] output;

        output[0] = (inputObject1.getValue1());
        output[1] = (inputObject1.getValue2());

        return output;
    }
}
```

The same method can be used in other classes by changing the method parameter to `Object2 inputObject2`. How do we accomplish this without redundant code?

Comment: do `Object1` and `Object2` have any relation to each other, i.e. a common parent class (You could use `Object` but that would all for any Object to be passed) or one is the parent of the other?

Comment: See my answer below. If I misunderstood the question, please clarify.

Comment: @twain249: He can't use Object, because Object has no method `String getValue1 ();`.

Answer (score 4):

The classes `Object1` and `Object2` could implement an interface:

```
public interface HasValues {

    public String getValue1();
    public String getValue2();
}
```

And your common method could be redefined to take an instance of that interface:

```
public String[] commonMethod(HasValues hasValues) {

    String[] output = new String[2];

    output[0] = hasValues.getValue1();
    output[1] = hasValues.getValue2();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it `String hasValue (int no);`?